# Propensity matching not matching

Tags: r

I’m trying to match controls to my disease counterparts (below is sample of the data called `mydata`

```
    AGE SEX HXCHF HXCOPD  CASEID Disease
1    44   1     0      0 2902568     1
2    61   1     0      0 3022106     1
3    31   0     0      0 8390810     1
4    49   1     0      0 1821150     1
5    48   1     0      0 1942796     1
6    25   1     0      0 1944197     1
7    61   0     0      0 2048336     1
8    51   1     0      0 2068689     1
9    30   0     0      0 2189285     0
10   31   1     0      0 2307730     0
```

Prior to being matched here is what the data looks like. You'll note there are 776 diseases cases and 750,638 non-disease cases.

```
     Stratified by Disease
                     0              1             SMD   
  n                  750638           776               
  AGE (mean (SD))     56.19 (15.54) 50.72 (14.32)  0.366
  SEX (mean (SD))      0.66 (0.47)   0.48 (0.50)   0.359
  HXCHF (mean (SD))    0.01 (0.08)   0.00 (0.05)   0.054
  HXCOPD (mean (SD))   0.04 (0.20)   0.03 (0.17)   0.052
```

I run the propensity model with variables onto which I want to match

```
        library(Matching)

        xvars <- c("AGE", "SEX", "HXCHF", "HXCOPD")
       
        greedymatch <- Match(Tr = Disease, M = 1, X = mydata[xvars])
   
        matched <- mydata[unlist(greedymatch[c("index.treated", "index.control")]),]
```

The output; rather than matching controls to disease it does something weird like this. I would expect to have 776 in control and 776 in disease instead there’s 4,696,274 in each one.

```
Stratified by Disease
                     0               1               SMD   
  n                  4696274         4696274               
  AGE (mean (SD))      53.32 (12.01)   53.32 (12.01) <0.001
  SEX (mean (SD))       0.65 (0.48)     0.65 (0.48)  <0.001
  HXCHF (mean (SD))     0.00 (0.00)     0.00 (0.00)  <0.001
  HXCOPD (mean (SD))    0.00 (0.04)     0.00 (0.04)  <0.001
```

I’m not seeing the error and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by self!

add `replace = FALSE` to the code

```
 greedymatch <- Match(Tr = Disease, M = 1, X = mydata[xvars], replace = FALSE)
```